# mySQL UNION add column into generated query result

Tags: mysql

so I have this query

```
SELECT a.*, b.full_name as salesman 
                    from sales a
                    LEFT JOIN user b ON a.salesman_id = b.id
                    WHERE a.deleted_at IS NULL AND (a.status = '1'  || a.status = '2' )  
                    AND a.balance <= 0
```

I want to add another column that is not related to any of the column from the first query. I want to add another column (payment_amount) into the generated result

After googled a while, i come into this query

```
SELECT a.*, b.full_name as salesman from sales a
                    LEFT JOIN user b ON a.salesman_id = b.id
                    WHERE a.deleted_at IS NULL AND (a.status = '1'  || a.status = '2' )  
                    AND a.balance <= 0

UNION ALL
SELECT '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',payment_amount from transaction
```

However, i cant see payment_amount column next to the generated result.

Please be reminded, that I can't edit the database.

the first query returns 28 columns. 
What is the problem here? have been dealing with it for hours. 
Any help given is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The column names in the result always come from the first query.

Comment: I wonder whether this actually runs .. coz UNION all expects same schema on both sides

Comment: @MysticForce MySQL will convert everything to strings if necessary to get them to the same data type.

Comment: @MysticForce Different column types might be OK but I think the number of columns has to match.

Comment: but it requires same no of columns atleast

Comment: if it is same , the last column is ambiguous

Comment: @MysticForce He has the same number. He said the first query returns 28 columns, and there are 28 columns in the second query.

Comment: okay ! somehow I missed seeing it !!

Comment: Don't use reserved word like transaction..check all reserved words https://www.drupal.org/node/141051

Answer (score 1):

union all will just add rows to your results from previous query. What exactly is ur problem?. Also if you are adding extra column in your 2nd query u need to add on dummy column in first.

```
SELECT a.*, b.full_name as salesman,"" as payment_amount   from sales a
                    LEFT JOIN user b ON a.salesman_id = b.id
                    WHERE a.deleted_at IS NULL AND (a.status = '1'  || a.status = '2' )  
                    AND a.balance <= 0

UNION ALL
SELECT '','','',... till 28 times,payment_amount from transaction
```

Comment: the payment_amount is blank sir, no data

Comment: ok.. so what are you expecting? Show us sample output you want.

Comment: if I write select payment_amount from transaction, there are data returned. I want to add those data into a new column from the generated query sir.

Comment: if your columns are number then you can use SUM() in all the fields in first query.  Before that change null to Zero .

Comment: How many Rows u get from SELECT payment_amount from transaction.?

Answer (score 0):

All rows in the result of a SQL query have the same column names. When you use `UNION`, the column names are taken from the names/aliases from the first subquery in the union. So in your case, the `payment_amount` will be in the column named `salesman`, since that's the corresponding column in the first subquery.

If you want it to be in a column of its own, you can add an extra column `0 AS payment_amount` to the first subquery, and an extra `''` to the second subquery.

```
SELECT a.*, b.full_name as salesman, 0 AS payment_amount
from sales a
LEFT JOIN user b ON a.salesman_id = b.id
WHERE a.deleted_at IS NULL AND (a.status = '1'  || a.status = '2' )  
AND a.balance <= 0

UNION ALL
SELECT '', '','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',payment_amount from transaction
```

Comment: all the payment amount now become 0 sir

Comment: There will be `0` payment amount on all the rows from the first query, and non-zero payment amounts on all the rows from the second query.

Comment: `UNION` doesn't merge the results from the two queries, they each come in their own sets of rows.

Comment: so basically,may i know the query above is used for what purpose sir ?

Comment: You said that the extra column is not related to the data in the first query. So it's just a way to get both sets of results with one query instead of two. When you loop over the results, check whether the first column is empty. If it's not empty you have a row from the first query, if it's empty it's a row from the second query.

Comment: If this isn't what you want, edit the question to clarify. Show some sample input data and the result you're trying to get from it.